# Finding the equation of a line that is the intersection of two planes?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

Can someone please explain this part of the problem attached herewith?
I have no idea what's going on in the highlighted region.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I use cross product to find the 'slope' of the line... this is so complicated!

Comment: @ChristopherMarley If you were looking for a different word, *direction vector* would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to eliminate fractions. Obviously $\lambda=8\mu+k$ since the fractions have a least common multiple of 8. Next, you want to figure out a possible value for $k$. So, multiplying out, the scalar part becomes:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 7 4 \\ \tfrac 5 8 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + k\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 3 4 \\ \tfrac 1 8 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{7+3k}{4} \\ \tfrac{5+k}{8} \\ k\end{bmatrix}$$

So we are looking for $7+3k\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $5+k\equiv 0 \pmod 8$. This gives $k=3$ as a possible value that will eliminate fractions, which is what was used.

Comment: But what's with the 0 and 1 in the z coordinates? How do we know that 3/4 and the 7/4 are the x coordinates and so on?

Comment: That's all from the non-highlighted section. If $z=\lambda$ then you want a 1 in the component of the vector multiplied by $\lambda$ and 0 in the component of the vector not multiplied by a variable. For the $x$ and $y$-components, just look at the system of equations.